# Having trouble setting up a HTTPS server in Express

Tags: node.js, express, https, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to setup my `express` app to work with `https`. This is what I've got so far:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var app = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private_key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.pem', 'utf8'),
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate_chain_1.pem', 'utf8'),
        fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate_chain_2.pem', 'utf8')
    ]
};
https.createServer(credentials, app, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('HTTPS server started on port ' + port + '...');
}).listen(port);
```

When I run, `curl -k -v -I https://127.0.0.1:8080`, I get this:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://127.0.0.1:8080/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.hiwarren.com
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
* Server certificate: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
* Server certificate: AddTrust External CA Root
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
X-Powered-By: Express
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 14
Content-Length: 14
< Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:32:28 GMT
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 19:32:28 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

And when I run `OpenSSL s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080/`

I get this error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Bruno-3:ssl brunomacedo$ OpenSSL s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080/
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hiwarren.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... certificate hash ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hiwarren.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4627 bytes and written 626 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 957E02E1D64D1F1E0ADBF4369057DD56B5FBE5A66269686DD590DF4D3B9A3D8C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 0B531BBFE5AA8AACEFC99749CD696926956419FFD61F7CCAF6E94C7574F6ECCEA31098D236E51F800F690D508E700444
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 25 2c fa ce af 2d f9 6e-8e fd 7e 9c f4 e6 c8 2b   %,...-.n..~....+
    0010 - 10 b6 f9 08 28 23 6f ec-98 0d c9 1d dd 78 34 25   ....(#o......x4%
    0020 - ab 21 55 37 02 42 a8 6c-84 9f 31 c0 60 ed 77 ae   .!U7.B.l..1.`.w.
    0030 - ab ea 4f 84 07 e7 d0 29-24 41 35 0f d7 01 09 21   ..O....)$A5....!
    0040 - a2 0f 1c 10 ab e4 47 67-f0 0d b0 f2 32 8d 3e f0   ......Gg....2.>.
    0050 - 10 30 35 82 48 df 09 ac-7c 12 98 11 99 7f 97 5b   .05.H...|......[
    0060 - d2 ef 47 69 4c 86 8b 2f-48 ff 62 58 08 7b 6c 7b   ..GiL../H.bX.{l{
    0070 - c2 f5 c5 1d 52 13 ad c4-95 d8 54 f8 a5 d2 5c 94   ....R.....T...\.
    0080 - c0 f3 c1 40 c1 44 5e b0-37 fa 3b 68 73 a7 ca 4f   ...@.D^.7.;hs..O
    0090 - ac d9 99 12 62 72 10 48-f1 9a 56 eb e6 89 d8 d4   ....br.H..V.....

    Start Time: 1429126474
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

I am able to solve the `error 20` when I run the same command using the `root_certificate` like this: `OpenSSL s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080/ -CAfile certificate_root.pem`.

So, here it is my new output:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Bruno-3:ssl brunomacedo$ OpenSSL s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080/ -CAfile certificate_root.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL Wildcard, CN = *.hiwarren.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hiwarren.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... certificate hash ...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hiwarren.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4627 bytes and written 626 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: CFD47EDA05B183790D25B32295550DB4DF74C483F3B1FEACD76C39548254FD9C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: DE16062EE238F854A4578F2E0F8FBE6874AF8550086E61C1D50EF3FBDB04F42355A6BD2072B8216B68477516E7F034C5
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 25 2c fa ce af 2d f9 6e-8e fd 7e 9c f4 e6 c8 2b   %,...-.n..~....+
    0010 - 16 26 97 0b a6 00 c6 12-d3 9a 91 1c d1 0f a4 d7   .&..............
    0020 - 96 30 88 54 3c e7 42 a1-db 4c 97 e6 68 5c d4 81   .0.T<.B..L..h\..
    0030 - f5 bf 7f 16 59 d2 32 bd-fa c7 9b c4 b5 1f a2 4d   ....Y.2........M
    0040 - 3b fe f9 af ad 29 58 31-c5 2e 2b 31 b1 52 62 9c   ;....)X1..+1.Rb.
    0050 - 1a 34 d0 c5 e4 e7 80 1f-d4 8a a3 0f 6b f4 2b d9   .4..........k.+.
    0060 - 4e 5d c0 8c 11 5a 0d de-00 23 19 0f 01 73 92 32   N]...Z...#...s.2
    0070 - 50 ee 08 56 4b a0 1c 20-c6 d7 9d de 58 b0 d4 70   P..VK.. ....X..p
    0080 - 2f b6 ca 3b 48 d0 bb fe-4c ea 6e 60 31 5d 4f 3d   /..;H...L.n`1]O=
    0090 - a4 6e f8 cd a2 15 1a 0e-36 6d b7 16 72 b9 e4 bf   .n......6m..r...

    Start Time: 1429126610
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

So, I think that the client needs to send this `root_certificate` somehow, in order to make it work, but I am not sure how can the client have it and send it.

Anyone has been through this? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl -k -v -I https://127.0.0.1:8080
...
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080
...
0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard/CN=*.hiwarren.com
i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
....
```

CA's no longer issuer certs for IP addresses. And they have not issued certs for [RFC 1918 addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918.txt) (like 127.0.0.1) in years.

You need to fix the certificate or fix name resolution. First, fix by including names like `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` in the `subjectAlternateName` (`SAN`) of the certificate.

Or second, fix it by making that server accessible by the name used in the certificate. You can do that by playing tricks with your local `hosts` file or DNS.

---

> `unable to get local issuer certificate`

Be sure to set the root certificate. The root certificate is `AddTrust External CA Root`.

Be sure the chain is being sent *with* the server certificate. Here, the chain is all the intermediate certificates *less* the root. You must already have the root certificate and trust it.

Comment: I've tried the same process for the deployed version of the app, so the `127.0.0.1` is 'fixed'. And the `AddTrust External CA Root` is the `certificate_root.pem` I passed along with the `-CAfile`. So, now I have two questions from your answer: 1) How do I set the root certificate? 2) How can I make sure that the chain is being sent with the server certificate? Thank you for your answers!!

Comment: For (1) with `cURL`, you set the root via the `--cacerts` option on the command line or `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, capath)`. For (1) with OpenSSL, use the `-CApath` option on the command line or `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` in a program.

Comment: For (2), you can use OpenSSL's `s_client`: `openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> -showcerts`. `showcerts` should  show the server sends 2 or 3 certificates. The first will be the end-entity (server) certificate, the other one or two will be the intermediate certificates required to build the path from the end-entity certificate to the root. The root should not be sent - you have to have it and trust it.

Comment: @bmpasini - A well configured server will send 2 or 3 certificates (the end-entity certifcate and the required intermediates) because that solves the [Which Directory](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Always_Provide_All_Needed_Certificates) problem for clients. Its a well known problem in PKI. To work around not-well-configured server, people stuff required intermediates in a collection like `cacerts.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats the exact question;

> > I am able to solve the error 20 when I run the same command using the root_certificate like this: OpenSSL s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8080/ -CAfile certificate_root.pem.
> >
> > So, I think that the client needs to send this root_certificate somehow, in order to make it work, but I am not sure how can the client have it and send it.

The error 20 disappeared on providing the root certificate. This is because the client could successfully validate(verify code 0(OK)) the server certificate using the CAfile provided.

When you didn't provide root certificate client had no clue on who the server is. The is no way to verify server's credentials. Hence the error 20.

The client **does not** send the root certificate to the server. How does one have it? You should know and have with you **publicly** available trusted CA certificates.
(For example, your browser comes pre-loaded with a set of well known CA certificates. Hence you are able to connect to any well known websites on HTTPS)